# Use the standard output as log path

Tags: windows, cmd, process, stdout, logfile

I need to run an external exe on windows machine, one of the arguments is a log path which the exe will write the progress info to

I would like to know if there is a way that i can make the external exe to write directly to the stdout instead of writing to a file

if I run the exe without any arguments it would not write anything to the stdout

There is no other argument that i could use

Comment: Try to specify [`con`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html#reserved) or `con:` as the log file…

Comment: Note: `con:` specifies the console, not STDOUT. (see `(echo hello)|find "e" && echo world` vs. `(echo hello>con:)|find "e" && echo world`. @aschipfl's suggestion might help you show the log on the console, but don't expect it to be redirectable or pipeable.

Comment: thank you I will give it a try

Comment: @Stephan and there is something i can to to make it redirectable?

Comment: nope - not from "outside" the application. Check the documentation, if it mentions some way to output to something other than a file. If waiting for the app to finish is an option, you can follow up with `type file.log`, but that's not "realtime", so I don't know if that is an option for you.